# SendKeys not sending values to my form on Chrome Browser

Tags: java, selenium, automation, testng

I am trying to execute a basic test case and looks like sendkeys is not sending the values. Here is the snippet of my code. My Property files have the value.

[image]

Below is my testcase

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the XPath is the problem. Anyway try injecting JS to set the value, something like this:

```
webdriver.executeScript("document.getElementByXpath('Xpath').setAttribute('value', 'new value for element')");
```

or like this

```
inputField = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.Xpath('Xpath'));
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'newvalue')", inputField);
```

Normally this ones work better with Name or ID attribute

Answer (score 0):

Look locators using is correct or not. provide path and html code, so can we can cross check it.

if xpath is correct but still senkeys not working, can try executeScript as suggested in another answer.

you can also, try with click on input field and then enter text. like this way also works most of these cases.